# Set up local domain in OpenWRT

Tags: networking, router, domain, openwrt, dnsmasq

I have a TP-Link TL-MR 3420 v2 router set up as a **Wi-Fi repeater** running **OpenWRT**. The router has been set up in a "briged mode". The router is connected to my phone's hotspot through OpenWRT's "join network" feature. DHCP is disabled on the router and is set up to forward DHCP requests to the phone.

I want to make the router's administration page (192.168.1.1) accessible through a local domain name (openwrt.wrt) via Wi-Fi without messing with hosts file and such. I've tried various different methods to try to set up the domain and all doesn't work.

Note that when I'm doing the settings, I'm connected to the router's Wi-Fi repeater hotspot on another phone and set up the phone to manually set a static ip address (192.168.1.128) and connect to the router's gateway address (192.168.1.1)

I would like to know a number of different ways to set up the local domain on the OpenWRT router and a brief step by step as I'm new to setting this up on a router.

Here are some additional information that might help
[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 1]
[image: Pic 1]

Edit: I have tried dnsmasq's dns forwarding feature with '/openwrt.wrt/192.168.1.1/' and it doesn't work. Also, if i change the dns from 8.8.8.8 to any other address while connected to the router, the phone cant even resolve 192.168.1.1. it seems to me that somehow i need to set up something on the router to be the '8.8.8.8' address guy but i dont know how. Maybe someone can show me how?

[image: Pic 1]

Comment: If I understand you correctly, your OpenWRT router is only acting as a range extender and not as a router or DHCP server. Your phone is presumably assigning the IP addresses. This means the phone is also responsible for telling DHCP clients what DNS servers to use. You would have to create your own DNS server and add the appropriate record to that DNS server that would resolve the domain name(s) in question to the IP address you wish for it to point to. Then, in your DHCP server settings, add the IP address of the DNS server as a DHCP option. I don't believe this will work with your setup.

Comment: I think Sam is somewhat right here. To keep a local DNS table on openwrt the first dns entry on openwrt would be (127.0.0.1) then 8.8.8.8 or whatever you are using for global dns.  The clients also need to have the openwrt address as the first dns server then global ones.

Comment: Also, not sure if that's bypassed when openwrt is in repeater or bridged modes.

Comment: @Sam Forbis well, that's partially true. I do use it as a Wi-Fi repeater most of the time. Sometimes I'll ssh into the router and do some things on it. Before i ssh into the router, I'll first set my client to the router's gateway.